# How to use K6 to test dotnet webapi rate limits actually work

Tags: asp.net-web-api, rate-limiting, k6

After adding rate limiters to a dotnet webapi, I would like to test that it actually work as intended and make sure to catch any unexpected changes.

For instance, given a TokenBucketRateLimiter with these options

```cs
new TokenBucketRateLimiterOptions
{
    TokenLimit = 5,
    ReplenishmentPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
    TokensPerPeriod = 2,
    QueueLimit = 0
});
```

How could I make sur that after consuming the given 5 token, the next calls will return http 429 until the replenished period time is elapsed?

I can create a test scenario like this one, within the threshold, to check that the calls return http status 200, but I have hard time figuring out how to test an actual expected error.

```js
import { check } from 'k6'
import http from 'k6/http'

export let options = {
    insecureSkipTLSVerify: true,
    scenarios: {
        constant_request_rate: {
            executor: 'constant-arrival-rate',
            rate: 1,
            timeUnit: '2s', 
            duration: '10s',
            preAllocatedVUs: 1, 
            maxVUs: 1,
        },
    },
};

export default () => {
    let result = http.get(url, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ...'
        }
    });
    
    check(result, {
        'is status 200': (r) => r.status === 200
    });
};
```

Comment: The `http_req_duration{expected_response:true}`, `http_reqs`, and `http_req_failed` metrics should get you the information you need (how many successful requests per time unit)

Comment: Asked differently: what do you want to actually test? That the "rate of successful requests is X"?